# PostgreSQL Socket Error after Installation

Tags: django, postgresql

I installed PostgreSQL(9.0.7) from EnterpriseDB on OS X 10.6. However, when I do a simple

```
$ psql -U postgres
```

I get this

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I am using it with Django. I tried changing the host variable in settings.py to

```
'HOST': '/tmp'
```

but I am still getting the same error message when I do a syndb. Any ideas? Thank you.

In my **postgresql.conf**

```
listen_addresses = '*'      
port = 5432             
unix_socket_directory = '/var/pgsql_socket/'
```

**Edit:**
I got it working. For some reason installed the newer version 9.1.3 and that error went away. I also got some help from a cheat sheet for PostgreSQL(http://od-eon.com/blogs/calvin/postgresql-cheat-sheet-beginners/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you started the database cluster?  You should be able to tell by running the command

```
ps auwwx|grep postg
```

You should see several postgresql processes.  If you do not, you need to start the database server.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/server-start.html

Comment: When I tried to start it I got this message     The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.

Comment: @Zach: See what OS user owns the data directory and start it as that user.  There should be a service script which already does that, if you have rights to run service scripts.